# PHP imap_rfc822_parse_headers getting BCC

Tags: php, imap, bcc

Why does the function `imap_rfc822_parse_headers` not contain BCC information? How do I get this information?

Comment: Because it's intended to be used on received mail that obviously will never contain the *B*CC (b for blind) header?

Comment: Probably because you don't have the source containing the `Bcc:` field. This function just parses an input string. The received mail does never contain the blind carbon copy addresses. It cannot magically uncover lost data.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

BCC is not the part of mail mime header.. thats what it is supposed to be. blind carbon copy..

More reference at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_carbon_copy